# Properties in an Interface

Tags: c#, .net, oop, properties, interface

In my interface, I have declared a property with setter and getter.

```
public interface ITestInterface
{
   string AProperty { get; set; }
}
```

When I code my class which inherit that interface, why I need to define these two properties again?

```
public sealed class MyClass: ITestInterface
{
   public string AProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem here is, that the same syntax has two different meanings for interfaces and classes. `AProperty { get; set; }` is in an interface is the declaration-only, in a class it's an automatically implemented interface.

Comment: If you wanted to provide some class members to inheriting classes without having to write them again in the inherited classes but also want to force the implementation of some signatures you provided, an abstract class would be a good choice. With interfaces you just provide signatures and force any class that implements that interface to have an implementation of these "prototypes".

Answer (score 4):

Because you are not inheriting from an interface, you are implementing the interface. (although they both share same syntax `:`)

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface { ... } //interface implementing
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass { ... } //inheriting from a class
```

Assume you are inheriting a candy box (not from your ancestors, in programming manner), it is something (not exactly) like you put the candy box in another box, now the outer box (the derived class, the inherited one) is inherited from candy box and have all the things candy box have, but if you want to implement (make) a candy box yourself you must build a box and put some candy in it. This is the way interfaces work.

Answer (score 3):

Your interface definition only tells there is a property with a getter and setter, not how it is implemented. You could use auto-implemented properties, but you are not required to.

Following the interface, this would be a valid implementation:

```
public sealed class MyClass: ITestInterface
{
    public string APROPERTY
    {
        get { return someField + " hello"; }
        set { someOtherField = value; }
    }
}
```

In an interface definition, `string AProperty { get; set; }` is the *declaration* of the property, while in a class, it means that the property is *auto-implemented*.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**

Because interfaces contain no more than a *definition* of a class, and cannot contain the actual *implementation* of any member functions. It's by design.

**Long answer**

First you have to realize that properties are basically *get* and *set* member functions with some simplified syntax. The question here is therefore: **why can't an interface definition contain an implementation of a member function?**

Well, in some languages (most notably: C++) you can.

If you have an inheritance chain, that's basically solved through lookup tables. Say that you have member function 1, then in all the classes in the inheritance chain, there's a table which contains a pointer to function 1. Once you call a member function, the call basically grabs the first entry from the table belonging to the type of your object, and calls that. This thing is called a *vtable* (and for more details, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)).

Now, in C++, VTables are very transparent to the developer: each class basically has a vtable and there's no such thing as a real 'interface'. This also means that all classes can have implementations and members such as fields. If you have a class with only *pure virtual members* (e.g. functions without an implementation), you have the C++ equivalent of an 'interface'.

In software engineering, these classes were often called 'interface' classes, because they contain only a definition of what's going on, not the actual implementation. Interfaces have the nice property that they describe functionality without actually going into the details, thereby giving the possibility to put 'boundaries' in your code. There are a lot of use cases for this, including (RPC) communication, a lot of design patterns, and so on.

In C++, a class can derive from multiple classes (multiple inheritance) with and without an implementation. Also, because interfaces are in fact more like 'abstract' classes than like 'interfaces' in C#, this means you can also add functionality there. The *vtable* that was previously described therefore contains pointers to functions in all the base classes.

The problems with this start when you're starting to add functionality to interface classes. For starters, let's say you have something like this (I'll do this in sort-of C#):

```
interface A { Foo(); } // basically an interface.
interface B : A { Foo(); } // another interface
class B : A { void Foo() {...} } // implementation of Foo, inherits A
class D : B,C { } // inherits both B, C (and A via both B and C).
```

What we're interested in here is what happens if you call `Foo` in class `D`. For that, we have to construct a *vtable* for class `D`. Basically this vtable would look like this:

```
Foo() -> C::Foo()
```

This means that if you construct an object of `D`, and call `Foo`, you'll end up calling the implementation of `Foo` in type `C`:

```
var tmp = new D();
tmp.Foo(); // calls C::Foo()
```

It becomes more difficult when we're changing the definition of B into something like this:

```
class B : A { void Foo() {...} } // changed into an implementation
```

Again, we try to construct the *vtable* for class `D` and we end up with a problem:

```
Foo() -> C::Foo() or B::Foo()???
```

The problem we're facing here is: what implementation of `Foo` are we going to use when calling that member? Also, what constructor are we going to call? And what about destruction order? In C++ there are workarounds for this called *virtual inheritance*.

While designing .NET and the C# language, they thought about past experiences with multiple inheritance and the implications of virtual inheritance and decided that it's not only a difficult thing to implement, but also very confusing for developers at best. As you've seen, these problems don't exist when you just add interfaces.

So, that's why you cannot have a property (or a method) in your interface.

Answer (score 0):

Interface contain property signatures not the actual definitions. You are actually requesting for any class implementing ITestInterface to implement get and set for AProperty. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is, that the same syntax has two different meanings for interfaces and classes. `AProperty { get; set; }` is in an interface is the declaration-only, in a class it's an automatically implemented interface.

So that term is dependent on the context.

```
public interface ITestInterface
{
    string AProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Declares the Property, but cannot implement it.

```
public sealed class MyClass: ITestInterface
{
    public string AProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Implements the interface, where the property is automatically implemented (which only works for classes).

Answer (score 0):

As others say interface is just a container for your methods and properties signatures. It needs implementation but this implementation signature will be perfectly match with one that is used in interface. Also it guarantees that all of this members can be accessed in a class instance as they are by default public properties and without implementation program will not compile at all.

Let's say you have interface:

```
public interface ITestInterface
{
    string AProperty { get; }
}
```

and class that implements it:

```
class MyClass : ITestInterface
{
   public string AProperty { get { if (DateTime.Today.Day > 7) return "First week of month has past"; return "First week of month is on"; } }
}
```

It's not possible to use auto-implemented properties and not possible to add setter in this class because interface property lacks set accessor and auto-implemented properties requires that interface contains auto-implemented properties signature ({ get; set;}). So in your example interface just declares properties and that's it.

Just by knowing what interfaces class has inherited you know what members are there and if you just want to use (or allow user to use) some of this methods (not allowing to change anything though) you can always upcast your class instance to one of these interface types and pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion here comes from the fact that auto properties (just the get and or set declarations) look the same in the interface and the implementation. The interface is merely a declaration (contract) of what a class must provide in order to be deemed an implementer of the interface. It is much clearer if you consider a method declaration in an interface vs its implementation in a class.

Interface = requirements;
Class = how those requirements are fulfilled

```
public interface ITestInterface
{
   string GetAProperty();
}

public class MyClass : ITestInterface
{
    public string GetAProperty()
    {
        // Do work...
        return "Value";
    }
}
```